# How to use certificates for Eduroam?

Tags: certificates

I am trying to connect to an eduroam network with Ubuntu 12.04. I understand you need to use certificates to log in to eduroam. I have looked on the University of East London site, but from here I don't know what to do. Can someone help me understand how to connect to the UEL eduroam service

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, Eduroam uses the following certificate on your laptop: `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt`

No need to download anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to get a certificate from your university, i am not sure if all of them use the same one - mine is  AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

you can try it, dl from here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/65dm62gcegrhbmx/AddTrustExternalCARoot%20%283%29.crt

Comment: I have downloaded the certificates for UEL but what do I do with them now? How do I install them?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. My college only had a tutorial for connecting with ubuntu 8.04. This tutorial stated, you should not use any certificate. With 12.10 i found this however is not the case. In my case I downloaded the certificate I found from another (foreign) university (AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt, like mentioned above) and used it to get a connection. I could use the instructions from other univesities as well, I only adjusted my username and password.